# how to make checkbox disabled angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

how can i make checkbox disable when i choose an item from comboboxes. forexample if i choose "ABONE", angular will make abone checkbox disable.

Note(example): DefinitionType : ABONE

[image]

```
                  <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2">Tanım Tipi<sup>*</sup></label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <select class="form-control" placeholder="Tanım Tipi" ng-options="field.value for field in DefinitionTypes" ng-model="DefinitionType"  required></select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><br />
```

Ekstra Tanım Tipi

```
                        <div class="checkboxinsameline" ng-repeat="item in DefinitionTypes">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="item.value" ng-click="DefinitionTypesChecked(item.id)" > {{item.value}}
                            </label>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><br />
```

Comment: You would add the attribute `disabled="{{isDisabled}}"` to the checkbox and then manage the value of `isDisabled` in the controller based on what is clicked in the drop down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to add this attribute on your input :

```
ng-disabled="item.value == DefinitionType.value"
```

This will disable your input when the value of your input will be equals to the value of your select model.